# Issues with logging in to ask a question

Tags: bug, login, redirection

This video link shows my issue with logging in

http://www.screenr.com/ucp7

So first I click on "Ask Question" and then it asks me to log in with an account. I attempt to log in with my google account, however it constantly says "We will redirect you" but simply refreshes the page. I think it might be a redirect fail? Please help me/fix this bug

EDIT:Clearing my cookies/cache seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: you have a very fast internet connection! Did you try clearing your browsers cache/cookies for SO? is it only in one browser?

Comment: Does this reproduce if you go incognito / private mode?

Comment: Deleting my cookies/cache seemed to fix the problem. Thanks iight!

Comment: Glad you have it sorted. I'll let a dev close this out, I think one will still be interested in seeing the screen cast you provided. That's a rather confusing experience, to say the least :)

Comment: Since it's [still happening](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239724/issue-with-meta-compsci-se-the-page-isnt-redirecting-properly) voting to reopen.