# Issue with Meta-CompSci SE ("the page isn't redirecting properly")

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, redirection, specific-site

I have a question about on-topic-ness for Computer Science SE. I went to [Meta-CompSci SE](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/) and signed up for an account.

I was not able to log in after signing up for an account. Clicking <kbd>log in</kbd> appeared to have no effect. So I moved directly to <kbd>Ask Question</kbd>. When I clicked <kbd>Ask Question</kbd>, I received:

[image]

Other stack exchange sites are fine.

Is there anything I can do to log in or ask a question?

Comment: No problem on my end when I try to reproduce.

Comment: @anorton - Damn, I was afraid of that....

Comment: Now, I do already have an account there, so if it's something bigger than just you, it might relate to account creation.

Comment: Can't repro as well, unlike @anorton I did not have an account. Maybe browser related, what browser you have? OS? When you try with a different browser, is it working?

Comment: @Shadow - I'm using Firefox 32.0.2. Let me go through a shutdown, clean cache, clean cookies, reboot sequence...

Comment: @jww cheers, was just about to suggest it, based on [this report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161109/issues-with-logging-in-to-ask-a-question). :)

Comment: @Shadow - it looks like a bad interaction with the EFF's [HTTPS Everywhere](http://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). Once I disabled it, I was able to log in on Meta CompSci SE. And hindsight is 20/20. Now that I know what the issue is, I get lots of hits for a search of HTTPS Everywhere.

Comment: @jww  Feel free to put that up as an answer for anyone else who might be running HTTPS Everywhere. Our SSL support is still in the works.

Comment: @Anna - I don't think this is worthy of a new question, but I just experienced a similar issue on Meta-Code Review SE. Disabling HTTPS Everywhere fixed it, too.

Comment: @jww Yeah, it'd likely affect any child meta site.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the issue was a bad interaction with the EFF's [HTTPS Everywhere](http://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). Once I disabled it, I was able to log in on Meta CompSci SE.

And hindsight is 20/20. Now that I know what the issue is, there are lots of hits for [HTTPS Everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=https+everywhere+is%3Aanswer).